# Diffrence between Students.Where(x=>x.City == "Lahore").ToList(); Students.ToList().Where(x=>x.City == "Lahore");

Tags: c#, linq

What is the difference between these linq queries:

```
Students.Where(x=>x.City == "Lahore").ToList();

Students.ToList().Where(x=>x.City == "Lahore");
```

Comment: don't know why this has been down voted. Perfectly reasonable simple question. I've up voted :)

Comment: As SWilko says, this seems like a reasonable question, not sure why it got down-voted (also up-voted the question). If down-voting it would be useful if you could clarify why this particular question has issues in a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Students.ToList().Where(x=>x.City == "Lahore")
```

The above line will fetch all Students from the database first and load them into memory (this could be a very slow process if there are many students), it will then create a query to filter the students by city. It will not actually evaluate this second filter until you enumerate the query (e.g. by using a for-each loop or by calling .ToList()).

```
Students.Where(x=>x.City == "Lahore").ToList();
```

In the line above you first create a query to get all students where the city is Lahore (Students.Where(x=>x.City == "Lahore")). This is not actually a result set (yet) but just a query capable of returning the results. To actually get the results into memory you need to call its enumerator which you do immediately by calling .ToList(). This then pulls only the students from Lahore into memory.

Answer (score 2):

If Students is an Iqueryable:

```
Students.Where(x=>x.City == "Lahore").ToList();
```

This will filter on the database and this:

```
Students.ToList().Where(x=>x.City == "Lahore");
```

will be filtered in memory.

Comment: Even in Linq-To-Object the first creates a list, so an in memory collection which can be reused multiple times without needing to execute the query again. The second will create a throwaway list from the complete input sequence and then creates a query on it. So you will always create that throwaway list and execute the query if you use this query.